# Format Entire Row Containing Todays Date - Office 365 (Latest version) on Mac

Tags: excel, office365, highlight

Trying to format the entire row to highlight todays date. Conditional format doesn't seem to have the ability to highlight the entire row.  Does have highlight the CELL only.  Googled this and the examples don't conform to what I see with my Excels Conditional Format options. The "New Rule" doesn't show any ability to enter a formula as the Googled examples show.  Any thoughts?

Again, many thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Use a formula-based rule and apply it to the entire range.

Comment: I'm not sure what your suggesting? Could you please expand / clarify? Are you suggesting I do this under Conditional Formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel rather silly.   Thank you BigBen for your answer.  I know see how and successfully formatted the row.